# how to generate soap request and get response in java coding

Tags: java, web-services, soap, netbeans, wsdl

can anyone help me to develop a java program which will interact with the webservice.

I created a simple webservice in netbeans.  it generates wsdl file and i take the url from it.

By using the wsdl file that is created in netbeans, i have to send soap request and get response in a java program.

I have the following piece of coding, but i have no idea on how to implement for my requirement

```
import javax.xml.soap.*;

public class SOAPClientSAAJ2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // Create SOAP Connection
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        String url = "http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx";
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

        // print SOAP Response
        System.out.print("Response SOAP Message:");
        soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);

        soapConnection.close();
    }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        String serverURI = "http://ws.cdyne.com/";

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("example", serverURI);

        /*
         Constructed SOAP Request Message:
         <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:example="http://ws.cdyne.com/">
         <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
         <SOAP-ENV:Body>
         <example:VerifyEmail>
         <example:email>mutantninja@gmail.com</example:email>
         <example:LicenseKey>123</example:LicenseKey>
         </example:VerifyEmail>
         </SOAP-ENV:Body>
         </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
         */
        // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("VerifyEmail", "example");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("email", "example");
        soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("mutantninja@gmail.com");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("LicenseKey", "example");
        soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("123");

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI + "VerifyEmail");

        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        /* Print the request message */
        System.out.print("Request SOAP Message:");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();

        return soapMessage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using JAX-WS instead of handcrafting your SOAP message. With JAX-WS you generate the code to create the SOAP/XML and to send/receive the message/response. All you're left to do is set the values for the content you need to pass. In this case that would be creating a VerifyEmail object, setting its two attributes and calling the send method of the generated web service client:

```
ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory;
VerifyEmailRequest request = objectFactory.createVerifyEmailRequest();
VerifyEmail msg = objectFactory.createVerifyEmail();
msg.setEmail("myemail@provider.com");
msg.setLicenseKey("myKey");
request.setVerifyEmail(msg);
VerifyEmailResponse response = myClient.verifyEmail(reques);
```

All the classes mentioned here would be generated for you by JAXB, which is used by JAX-WS. You can find more detailed info [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/twbs_jaxwsclientfromwsdl.html).

Comment: This is nice if you can, but this is not always the case. My client wants me te resend logged soap messages to the endpoint. Figuring out which exact method to call of which service is a pain and resending the SOAPEnvelope is much more practical.

Comment: I don't see any problem with that. If at any point you need the XML representation of a message you can use a JAXB Marshaller to serialize the message to XML.

Comment: True. It proved easier, however, to just open a socket to the endpoint , set the required HTTP header and stream the header and SOAP envelope to it.